# Libraries for parsing PDF, PostScript, and/or DjVu

Tags: pdf, postscript, djvu

What I want to do is pretty simple: given a PDF/PS/DjVu file containing a paper/book, find the authors and title of the paper (any other metadata would be good, but less needed). This recognition doesn't have to be perfect, but I'd like to make it as good as I can. I am looking for open-source .NET and/or Java libraries (preferably .NET) which allow to access metadata and contents of these files.

For PDF I've found [PDFBox](http://incubator.apache.org/pdfbox/) (.NET/Java) and [PDF Library](http://www.codeplex.com/pdflib) (.NET), but there may be better alternatives I am not aware of; for Postscript and DjVu, I haven't found anything.

Answer (score 1):

For most PDF manipulation we use [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/).  This is a port of the original Java implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Another PDF library is [PDFSharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/).  It has pretty decent read/parse capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

For DjVu, you can use the commerical SDK from [CamiNova](https://www.caminova.net/en/downloads/download.aspx?id=17) or the open source library, DjVu Libre.

Answer (score 0):

For Djvu you can use the C# library located at: https://github.com/Telavian/DjvuNet