# Parsing a book or article pdf to get metadata

Tags: pdf, metadata

I want to extract metadata (title, authors, publication date etc.) from the pdf files which I know they are books or articles. Is there any template for books and articles? While parsing, how can I know that I found the right thing? Which tools or libraries can I use?

There is a question partly about my question: [Libraries for parsing PDF, PostScript and/or DjVu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161465/libraries-for-parsing-pdf-postscript-and-or-djvu)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is now standard for a layout of PDF books and  layout is always specific to the particular publisher. But I think that if you want to automate the classification of books stored in PDF format then you might consider the following scenario:

- take 2 to 5 major publishers (that 80% from 80/20 Paretto principle) and check first pages of PDF book for their specific headers or footers, like "published by PublisherName"
- compare the structure of the source PDF with patterns you have created on the previous step. You may extract structure of the visual layout working with low-level libraries like [iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/) or with high-level libraries like commercial [PDF Extractor SDK](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/pdfextractorsdk/index.html) that provides API to access by column/row.
- sort out input books by these filters to find out which publisher made the book.
- apply the pre-coded extraction for the selected publisher to the book and the layout this or that publisher uses.

This way you may try to cover major publishers and leave non-major publishers to for the manual categorization. Please also note that PDF files includes `Producer`, `Author`, `Title` fields as standard header that you may use for the additional source of information about books.

*Disclosure: I'm related to ByteScout, maker of PDF Extractor SDK and free [PDF Multitool](https://bytescout.com/products/pdfmultitool/index.html)*